# Changing static class variables

Tags: python, class, static-variables, class-variables

How is it possible to change static variables of a class? I want it to be changed by some sort of input.

```
class MyClass: 
    
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 4

    def __init__(self, var3, var4):
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4
```

It is var1 og var2 that i want to be changable, or want to know how to change.

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
class Whatever():
    b = 5
    def __init__(self):
        Whatever.b = 9999

boo = Whatever()
print(boo.b) # prints 9999

boo.b = 500
print(boo.b) # prints 500

Whatever.b = 400
print(boo.b) # prints 500

# since its a static var you can always access it through class name
# Whatever.b
```

Comment: this is wrong. The last `print(boo.b)` prints 500, not 400.

Comment: You are right @PoweredByRice. The reason why, in my understanding, is that the line `boo.b = 500` is creating an object variable, `boo.b`, which is shadowing the class variable `whatever.b`. So, when in the last line you print `boo.b`, you are printing the "new" object variable. This can be checked by creating the whatever class from scratch, and then running `boo = whatever()`, `whatever.b = 400` and `print(boo.b)`. the result now would be 400.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the class variables, you can assign them to the variables in the `__init__` scope:

```
class MyClass: 
  var1 = 1
  var2 = 4
  def __init__(self, var3, var4):
    self.var1 = var3
    self.var2 = var4

c = MyClass(100, 200)
>>>c.var1, c.var2
```

Output:

```
(100, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you need to rebind the class attributes. You can also do so later when the object is created:

```
mc = MyClass(1, 2)
mc.var1 = 20
mc.var2 = 40
```

There is no difference between an attribute created or changed within the class body to one created outside by assigning to an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the class variables by class name as shown below:

```py
class MyClass: 
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 2
        
MyClass.var1 = 10 # By class name
MyClass.var2 = 20 # By class name

print(MyClass.var1) # Class variable
print(MyClass.var2) # Class variable
```

Output:

```
10
20
```

Be careful, if you try to change the class variables by object, you are actually adding new instance variables but not changing the class variables as shown below:

```py
class MyClass: 
    var1 = 1 
    var2 = 2 
        
obj = MyClass()
obj.var1 = 10 # Adding a new instance variable but not changing the class variable
obj.var2 = 20 # Adding a new instance variable but not changing the class variable

print(MyClass.var1) # Class variable
print(MyClass.var2) # Class variable
print(obj.var1) # New instance variable
print(obj.var2) # New instance variable
```

Output:

```
1
2
10
20
```